# What is omitted after でも in this panel?

Tags: manga

From Oshi no ko ch. 126, Ichigo, the guy in the panel below, realized that he was conditioned by Aqua to go to a particular store from the very beginning.

[image]

Notice that in the second panel, 時間の問題でも ended with eclipses. It makes me wonder how 時間の問題でも should end grammatically. The only possible ending I can think of is 時間の問題でもある. I don't know if it sounds correct in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ある/ない are usually good options, but they don't seem fit here.

I suspect that there's a pose between 時間の問題 and でも... and the sentence is interpreted as below

> ってことは時間の問題(だった。/だったのか？)　でも...

In this interpretation, でも works like "but...".

Answer (score 0):

In this case the ellipses functions to indicate uncertainty (the spoken equivalent would be trailing off as you float an idea.) Nothing is really omitted, but if you wanted to replace it with concrete phrasing 最初から時間の問題だったのかもしれない would have the equivalent meaning.

Comment: There is always something implicitly understood when an ellipsis occurs in Japanese, in this case one can imagine various possibilities, for example, でも［あるかな・あったかな].